# Two videos on one page carousel - Chromium

Tags: javascript, video, raspberry-pi, html5-video, chromium

I have 2 vides hosted on a server.

In Chromium browser (Version 65.0.3325.181) https://server/index.html is loaded.

Using Javascript,  2 video elements are inserted after window.onload and the 1st one is started.

Both inserted like:

```
let video = document.createElement('video');
        video.setAttribute('width', '100%');
        video.setAttribute('height', '100%');
        video.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');

        let source = document.createElement('source');
        source.setAttribute('src', <http://server/video/path>);
        source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');

        video.appendChild(source);
```

After finish video.on('ended') video element becomes hidden. And next video element becomes visible and started.

Everything works fine:

2 video elements created and hidden.
Immediately 1st video element started and playing ..
On 1st video ended - it becomes hidden 
Second video becomes visible and started ... successfully reach its end and becomes hidden again...

then start again from 1st video...

I have following observation.

First video is always playing smootly after initially cached.

Second video is always playing with glitches and freezes of few milliseconds.

I am using Chromium on Raspberry Pi 3.

When first video starts: CPU is like 40-50-60%

Everytime the second video starts: CPU is like 120-220% and with glitches and freezes.

The issue is not video or encoding related, because when i switch places: the new 2th video (which was 1st before) becomes the problematic one. Always the second video!

Why this can be? 
Can you give me some clue or direction what it might be?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that the first video is using the Raspberry PI's built in Broadcom HW video decoding, but the second one is having to fall back to SW decoding.

The same affect can be seen on many computers if you play multiple videos and exceed what decoding the platform can handle in HW - a typical approach is to fall back on some form of SW decoding, or perhaps to simply give priority to the first video(s) playing.

There are also restrictions to the codec and frame rates supported on most video cards, although this does not sound like the issue you are seeing as the video sounds like it plays fine when it is the only or the first video.